# V10 interface problems

Tags: version-10, interface

Has anyone noticed the following?

1. Sometimes when I bring up the Help->Wolfram Documentation there is no text field to type into.
2. When I bring up Find and Replace there are two text fields for Find: and Replace with: but no other controls or buttons (No buttons Find Next, Find Previous, Replace etc).  In this case on my system - win7-64 - the dialog box is unnaturally tall (whole height of screen).
3. Syntax highlighting seems somewhat erratic - defined symbols stay the wrong color for a while.  Symbols that are part of a function signature, say f[x_]:=... stay the wrong color for a while as well.

Restarting Mathematica restores these.

Comment: Sounds like a good list of problems to send to WRI support. I don't have them.

Comment: I definitely have noticed #3.

FWIW, `$Version` evaluates to

`"10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"`

Comment: I'm on Linux and I've been experiencing (1) for many versions and still do, so I'm pretty much used to it. I think it's a problem with the graphics toolkit they are using. For me the text field is restored when I click into the general area where it's supposed to be. I can also confirm (3), but again, I've had that problem in earlier versions.

Comment: Reported to WRI support.